# Spring Message source with newlines

Tags: spring

I want to make a newline \n in my message source file. I tried with '\n' but its not working. Can anybody help me ?

my text looks like:

```
error = User error 42 '\n' Try again!
```

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `<br/>` instead. should work.

Newlines in `HTML` are not represented by the `\n` character, but by the `<br />` element.

Comment: hi. the <br/> workings fine. but i also need it for a MimeMessage which is a string is there way to escape a \n any how ?

Comment: you can use String.replace function to replace <br/> with \n while creating MimeMessage.

Answer (score 0):

## Just use \n.

You can use `white-space: pre-wrap` style on your HTML element to respect the newline character.

Putting HTML in the message, as the accepted answer suggests, is **not** a good idea, as

1. you'd need to skip HTML escaping when outputting this string, which is a security risk if the message also contains parameters that are filled in with user input, and
2. if you want to use the message for non-HTML purposes as well, for example logging the message, the `<br>` will show up there.